# ASP .NET Identity 2.0 and LINQ compound query with group by

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, group-by

I am using ASP .NET Identity 2.0 as my user manager. Right now I want to retrieve the list of all users with RoleId different from "4". My LINQ query looks like this:

```
            var userList = from entry in this.UserManager.Users
                           from roles in entry.Roles
                           where roles.RoleId != "4"
                           group entry by entry.Id into g
                           select new { g.Id, g.UserName, g.Email, g.EmailConfirmed, g.PhoneNumber, g.PhoneNumberConfirmed, g.Roles };
```

Unfortunately, `group by` completely doesn't work and `g`'s parameters are not recognized. Without grouping the list contains separate rows for every user->role and it is not my desired effect. What is wrong in my query?

Edit:
Of course each user has a number of roles. If one of them is `RoleId == 4` then I do not want his record to be retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any need for grouping. Try this much simpler query:

```
 var userList = this.UserManager.Users
                  .Where(u => u.Roles.All(r => r.Id != "4"));
```

This should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: This solved my problem. I only had to change 'r =>  r.Id' into 'r => r.RoleId' Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userList = (from entry in this.UserManager.Users
               //group entry by entry.Id into g  //I don't know why you need to group this,usually `id` is primary key
               select new { entry.Id, entry.UserName, entry.Email, entry.EmailConfirmed, entry.PhoneNumber, 
               entry.PhoneNumberConfirmed, Roles=entry.Roles.Where(r=>r.RoleId != "4").ToList() })
              .Where(g=>g.Roles.Count>0);
```

if there is no role's in result, the user will be removed

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. g's parameters are still not recognized.

Comment: Yes but I still have this error: "Error 3 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,MyApp.Models.ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,MyApp.Models.ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"